# Faster repetitive uses of bz2.BZ2File for pickling

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pickle, bz2

I'm pickling multiple objects repeatedly, but not consecutively. But as it turned out, pickled output files were too large (about 256MB each).

So I tried `bz2.BZ2File` instead of `open`, and each file became 1.3MB. (Yeah, wow.) The problem is that it takes too long (like 95 secs pickling one object) and I want to speed it up.

Each object is a dictionary, and most of them have similar structures (or hierarchies, if that describes it better: almost the same set of keys, and each value that corresponds to each key normally has some specific structure, and so on). Many of the dictionary values are numpy arrays, and I think many zeros will appear there.

Can you give me some advice to make it faster?

Thank you!

Comment: `bzip2` is known to be slow, have you tried `zlib`? not clear what are you asking, use multi-thread or multiprocessing to speed-up?

Comment: @georgexsh Thanks for your comment. I switched to lz4 (as stated in my answer), and it just solved the whole problem I had. The compression time decreased to less than a second per each object.

Comment: nice to learn that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using [lz4](https://lz4.github.io/lz4/), which is a blazingly fast compression algorithm.

There is [a python wrapper](http://python-lz4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which can be installed easily:

```
pip install lz4
```